# Make directory in VBscript relative to workbook running the macro

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, filesystemobject

I'm using the following to create a folder:

```
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Create a new folder
oFSO.CreateFolder "C:\MyFolder"
```

But I'd like the folder location to be in the same place as the excel workbook running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

To return the path of the current workbook.

Something like this:

```
Dim oFSO As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

oFSO.CreateFolder ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyFolder"
```

Comment: No problem!  If this answered your question would you mind clicking the green check mark to accept this as an answer?  It adds to my point total which helps build my reputability around here.  I'd appreciate it!

Comment: done. I have another question about moving that file... should i post it anew or add to this one?